# Save data from Google Spreadsheet history

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I used a Google form and inadvertently deleted a few rows.

**I need to use the rows again**. I see them with history but I can't save them and I can't print them.

**How can I restore the data**?

Answer (score 2):

With the following guidance, you should be able to retrieve the info:

1. First you need to open a new spreadsheet.
2. Select the "old" spreadsheet again.
3. Open the revision history:
   [image: List item]
4. If you select the desired version, then you can restore that version:
   [image]
5. Copy the content of the sheet into the newly created spreadsheet.
6. After you've copied the info, restore back to the original version.

I hope it works out !